# How to connect JavaScript and Html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So i want to connect my array from javaScript to my html, some one can explain how can i do that? i am only able to find when the javascript is in the same html.

html file:
rest of the code in html ...

```
    <label for="eye">Which eye color does the character have?</label>
    <select name="eye" id="eye">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="brown">Brown</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<script>
    src = "js/eindopdracht.js"
</script>
```

js file:

```
var eyeColors = ["blue", "brown","green"];
```

Comment: You can loop through/iterate through your array and use `document.createElement()` and append them to the `<select>` Now all you have to do is a little research and you will be able to do this on your own. Also the `src` attribute should be inside the `<scrpt>` tag. `<script src...`

Answer (score 2):

the correct tag for you to use is is:

`<script src="js/eindopdracht.js"></script>`

this is how to include an external javascript file.

If you want to add javascript code inline then you would do:

```
<script>
  console.log("this is inline javascript");
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for correcting me about the <script src="js/eindopdracht.js"></script>